# Чи є єдине правило вживання кличного відмінку для словосполучень?

Tags: кличний-відмінок

Наскільки мені відомо, словосполучення виду ім'я та по-батькові у кличному відмінку відмінюються разом: *Іван**е** Петрович**у***

А також, з давніх часів читання журналу «Перець» пам'ятаю таке само використання у словосполученнях виду *Друж**е** «Пер**че**»*

З іншого боку, постійно бачу випадки, коли лише одне слово знаходиться у кличному відмінку: *любий друж**е***.

А в інших випадках, як-то *пан Президент*, можна зустріти обидва варіанти:

- *пан**е** Президент*
- *пан**е** Президент**е***

Чи існує єдине, регулярне правило, яке регулює використання кличного відмінку для словосполучень?

Comment: «Любий друже» — обидва слова в кличному відмінку. (Просто кличний відмінок прикметників збігається з називним.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Правопис 2019](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=96) вже иншої думки, де за основу є окличуваня всїх можливих слів.

> **Примітка 1.** У звертаннях, що складаються з двох загальних назв, форму кличного відмінка мають обидва слова: *добро́дію бригади́ре, па́не лейтена́нте*.
>
> **Примітка 2.** У звертаннях, що складаються із загальної назви та імені, форму кличного відмінка набувають і загальна назва, і власне ім’я: *бра́те Пе́тре, дру́же Гри́цю, коле́го Степа́не, лі́карю І́горю, па́не Віта́лію, побрати́ме Іва́не*.
>
> **Примітка 3.** У звертаннях, що складаються із загальної назви та прізвища, форму кличного відмінка набувають і загальна назва, і власне ім’я: *дру́же Макси́менку; коле́го Євгенищуку́ , па́не Кова́лю*; можливі також поєднання форми кличного відмінка іменника загальної назви та форми кличного відмінка прізвища, однакової з формою називного відмінка: *дру́же Макси́менко; коле́го Євгенищу́к, па́не Кова́ль*.
>
> **Примітка 4.** У звертаннях, що складаються з двох власних назв — імені та по батькові, обидва слова мають закінчення кличного відмінка: *Володи́мире Хомичу́, Пе́тре Кузьмичу́ , Яросла́ве Андрі́йовичу*

Answer (score 6):

[«Український правопис» 2015](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par53p4prym1):

> **Примітка 1.** У звертаннях, що складаються з двох загальних назв, форму кличного відмінка має як перше слово, так і друге, хоч друге слово може мати й форму називного відмінка: *добродію бригадире* (*бригадир*), *пане лейтенанте* (*лейтенант*).
>
> **Примітка 2.** У звертаннях, що складаються із загальної назви та імені, форму кличного відмінка набуває як загальна назва, так і власне ім’я: *брате Петре*, *друже Грицю*, *колего Степане*, *пані Катерино*, *товаришу Віталію*.
>
> **Примітка 3.** У звертаннях, що складаються із загальної назви та прізвища, форму кличного відмінка має тільки загальна назва, а прізвище завжди виступає у формі називного відмінка: *друже Максименко*, *колего Іваничук*, *добродійко Скирда*, *товаришу Гончар*.
>
> **Примітка 4.** У звертаннях, що складаються з двох власних назв — імені та по батькові, обидва слова мають закінчення кличного відмінка: *Володимире Хомичу*, *Галино Іллівно*, *Маріє Василівно*, *Петре Кузьмичу*, *Ярославе Андрійовичу*.

Хоча це знаходиться в § 53, тобто формально (за ієрархією розділів правопису) стосується лише однини другої відміни. Але можна припустити, що текст цих приміток насправді стосується всіх відмін (і чисел). Тим більше, що приклади в цих примітках містять слова і однини першої відміни (*колега*, *Катерина*, інші) і невідмінювані (*пані*).