# Кличний відмінок і прикметники

Tags: прикметники, кличний-відмінок

Зазвичай кличного відмінка прикметники, [короткі](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96#%D0%92%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%8E%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2) і повні, не мають і, схоже, [не мали](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA#%D0%86%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F).

Але нерідко натрапляю щось на зразок: [*любо Україно*](https://www.google.com.ua/search?lr=lang_uk&q=%22%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BE+%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%BE%22), [*рідно мати*](https://www.google.com.ua/search?lr=lang_uk&q=%22%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE+%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%22), [*красно дівчино*](https://www.google.com.ua/search?lr=lang_uk&q=%22%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE+%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%22) ітд., де помітна закономірність. Що це, якщо це не щось окреме кличне як відмінок чи форма? Якщо загалом, то прикметники можуть мати щось кличного, нп. так в близькій [латині](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocative_case#Latin) чи далекій [гіндустані](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocative_case#Hindi-Urdu), де обі мови — індоевропейські. Можна також зазначити, що самі прикметники подеколи виконують роль іменника в реченні, що теж може бути одною з підстав окличувати їх: *сліпий*, *старий* ітд.

Тож, якщо це кличний відмінок, то як зазвичай відмінюють, бо тут не згадано мʼяку ґрупу — лише можу припускати про *син~* *-є* чи *-ьо*, а також чоловічий рід, хоча є [непідтверджена згадка](https://www.wikiwand.com/uk/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F:%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA#%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2), що для твердої — *шановн~* *-ию*.

Comment: Related: https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/1203/